# What is the effect of adding a word separator in Elastic Search multi-match query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query in Elastic search:

What is the difference in specifying a + character between the 2 search terms ?

Thus: "query": "animation+function"  OR   "query": "animation function"

```
"query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "animation+function",
          "type": "best_fields",
          "fields": [
            "title",
            "body"
          ]
        }
```

thx
Marc

Comment: It is all depends on which analyzer you use. if you use a standard analyzer, It will have no difference , standard tokenizer removes those punctations https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/standard-tokenizer.html